# Umbraco - how can I automatically make changes to an XML file with a Media item upload or delete event?

Tags: xml, flash, umbraco

I'm looking for a solution to the following problem and I'm not sure if this is possible to do with Umbraco.

We have a Flash movie which will read in images/paths to images and an accompanying title via XML and we need to be able to manage these through Umbraco.

Is it possible to program an event for when an image is uploaded or removed from this specific folder so that it makes changes to the XML file and so it adds or removes the corresponding data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this from one of two ways - so that it's easiest for your content managers, or so it's most manageable from a code and resource perspective.

- Easy for editors: You could write a .NET service which would use a FileSystemWatcher, which could then update details inside Umbraco by calling the Umbraco webservice API methods, yes. This means your content editors can just copy-and-paste images into a given folder to their hearts' desires. Downsides - FSW's are memory-heavy, debugging system services aren't much fun, and generally speaking you could avoid this scenario by...
- Manageable for editors/programmers: using Umbraco's built-in media manager, content managers can then upload new images through the admin interface, and the underlying XML and information gets updated accordingly, which then propagates through to your Flash site.

HTH,

Benjamin